# use comparison operators continuous in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, comparison, comparison-operators

Hello my name is parsa and I'm a c# programmer i want to use comparison operators continuous for example imagine we have three Variables named V1,V2,V3

```
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int V1 = rnd.Next(1,5), V2 = rnd.Next(1, 5), V3 = rnd.Next(1, 5);
```

each of them is equal to a random number between 1 and 4 then we want to see are they equal together and are they equal to 3 ? we have to use this code

```
    if(V1 == V2 && V1 == V3 && V1 == 3)
        //body
```

if i want to use it such as this this it will be get me a error !

```
    if(V1 == V2 == V3 == 3)
        //body
```

can i use it such as code i wrote ?

Comment: Create a IComparable Class where you can create a custom CompareTo() method that will check if the values are equal : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: The "advantage" of @AlphaDelta's suggestion is that no one who reads your code a year from now will have a clue what it's doing.  Writing non-idiomatic code is a bad idea.  Stick with the clear and easy to read

Comment: C# has rules.  If you evaluate `V1 == V2 == V3 == 3`, the first thing that happens is that `V1 == V2` is evaluated to one of `true` or `false` (i.e., a boolean).  Then `(V1 == V2) == V3` gets evaluated.  The stuff in parentheses has already been determined to be a boolean, so you get an expression comparing a boolean and the type of V3.  Your error (which you should include in your post) most likely says you can't use `==` between a boolean and whatever type V3 is

Comment: @DavidG : I'm trying to give real answer to problems base on my experience.  Not closing a posting because a novice doesn't know how to ask a proper question.  How do you expect novices to learn if people just close the questions.

Comment: @jdweng No, I'm saying your comments are almost always incorrect. It's got nothing to do with closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in C#; however, if you are comparing a variable against several patterns (like constant patterns or type patterns),  (since C# 9.0) you can write

```cs
if(v is a or b or c)
```

Note that you can use C# 9.0 in Visual Studio 16.8 or later. It was introduced together with .NET 5. You can use most of the C# 9.0 features (including pattern matching) in older framework versions by adding a LangVersion tag to the *.csproj manually.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See also: [What's new in C# 9.0 / Pattern matching enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: It runs in C# 9.0.